# "No repository found at:" Error while install TestNG plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I have installed latest eclipse version - 4.19.0 and tried to install TestNG plugin from the "Eclipse Marketplace" getting error:

```
"eclipse.buildId=4.19.0.I20210303-1800
java.version=15.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository
Error
Tue May 04 11:25:24 IST 2021
No repository found at http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/.
"
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because bintray is down and need to update the [TestNG references](https://groups.google.com/g/testng-users/c/f6I6lmfHkmc)

> hi guys, because bintray.com sunset on May 1, so we have moved the update-site to github,
>
> - new update site url: https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site
> - the source is at https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-update-site

> we will update the url on eclipse marketplace soon.

> see more details: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/511#issuecomment-827179825

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is still looking for answer
I ran into similar problem when installing TestNg on latest Eclipse 2021-06
Both the bintray and beust urls did not work

so I went to new update url https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site copied latest Versioned update site URL https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.4.0

In Eclipse Help → Install new software  > Add

Name: TestNg

Location: paste the copied versioned url - https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.4.0

Click Add